# Ef Core 3.1 and Identity framework combining DB Context

Tags: c#, ef-core-3.1

I am trying to merge my application context with my db context I have tried various solutions but none of them are working for ef core 3.1.

```
public class AppManagerDBContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public AppManagerDBContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("name=DefaultConnection");
        }
    }

    public DbSet<BmiInformation> BmiInformation { get; set; }
    public DbSet<WorkOuts> WorkOuts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<BmiInformation>().ToTable("BmInformation");            
    }
}
```

This is the full error that I am getting I thought all I had to do is inherit from `IdentityDbContext` is there something else I have to do in .NET Core 3.1 and EF Core?

```
Add-Migration MyFirstMigration -Context AppManagerDBContext
Build started...
Build succeeded.
```

**Error**

> The AppManagerDBContext constructor must be a
>   DbContextOptions. When registering multiple
>   DbContext types make sure that the constructor for each context type
>   has a DbContextOptions parameter rather than a non-generic
>   DbContextOptions parameter.

**Edit 1**
Ok I solved the issue with the following however I am now getting a new error.

My User Info class

```
public class UserInfo : IdentityUser
{
    // These two new fields are added here
    [PersonalData]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [PersonalData]
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
}
```

**Error 2**

> The entity type 'IdentityUserLogin' requires a primary key to
>   be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type call
>   'HasNoKey()'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must inject a `DbContextOptions` object into your `DbContext`, which type paremeter must be the object type you are injecting into.

In your case

```
public class AppManagerDBContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public AppManagerDBContext(DbContextOptions<AppManagerDBContext> options) : base(options) { }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Both errors are quite explanatory.

You must mark one or more properties of your entity to be a primary key.
If you want so, try

```
public class UserInfo : IdentityUser
{
    // DatabaseGenerated is optional.
    // Only in case you want to delegate the key generation
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [PersonalData]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [PersonalData]
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
}
```

Or, if you want none, configure the entity as unkeyed.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<BmiInformation>().ToTable("BmInformation");
    modelBuilder.Entity<UserInfo>(u =>
    {
        u.HasNoKey();
    });           
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Please see edit 2 above I have fixed that problem already your answer came after my edit but now have a second issue please see error 2

Comment: Thanks that was indead the answer I thought it was as simple as a key but wasnt sure I though UserInfo just added onto the existing user tables is that not the case?

Comment: Depending on your entities strategy and what you registered into the `DbContext` as `DbSet<>`

Comment: Could you provide example how I would extend it im wanting to save profile info such as likes against the user table.

Comment: I suggest you to read [this article](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/inheritance) where are explained three strategies about entity polymorphism in Entity Framework. However, there's no build-in generic solution for this, I'd have to choose what fits in your case.

Comment: Glad to hear it.